# Rails 4 user routing

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

```
<%= link_to "Whatever", current_user %>
```

is linking to `/user.id`

My routes are setup like this

```
resource :user, except: [:index, :destroy]
```

So it should be linking to `/user`, right?

When I visit `/user` it says "Couldn't find User without an ID".

My user show action looks like this

```
def show
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
end
```

Comment: no it should be linking to /user/id  you told it not to generate a index route which would be /user

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason you are getting `/user.id` is because you have defined your routes as

`resource :users, except: [:index, :destroy]`

Note the `singular resource` which will create all the routes without any `:id`. As you don't have an accepting param within the route, the `current_user` that you are passing is matched to the `format` i.e., like `.html, .js, etc.` which in your case becomes `.id`

I would recommend using `resources` (note the plural)

`resources :users, except: [:index, :destroy]`

This will resolve the error `Couldn't find User without an ID` as you would be passing an params `id` within your route.

**NOTE:**

As per Rails convention, controller name should be `plural`.  For `UsersController`, resources should be `resources :users`

Comment: Now I'm getting an error on /user/new "uninitialized constant UserController". In case you're wondering, my usersController is named "class UsersController".

Comment: Got it working. I didn't realise how many things needed to be changed like to form_for url. It would be nice though to take advantage of the dropped /id if possible, since I don't want users to be able to view other users show pages. So the /id is redundant.

Answer (score 0):

I have had this happen many times. My fix is to use the path helpers.

```
<% link_to "Whatever", user_path current_user %>
```

This will drop the `.id` and make it `/user/id`